# Object not reference when editing webpart(Http method 405 not allowed)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, web-part

When you click on edit webpart, the page will not display and give an error:

> Http method 405 not allowed.

In the ULS logs, I find the following error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.   
at 
at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()     
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ToolPane.OnSelectedWebPartChanged(Object sender, WebPartEventArgs e)    
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, WebPartEventArgs e)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.BeginWebPartEditing(WebPart webPart)    
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.ShowToolPaneIfNecessary()

at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.OnPageInitComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e)   
at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)    
at System.Web.UI.Page.OnInitComplete(EventArgs e)    
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Web Part Page Maintenance page to check if there is web part in the page. Add “?contents=1” after the URL of the page.

http://yourserver/SitePages/page8.aspx?contents=1

if there is web part, check if it is open on the page.

And create a new page and add a web part, and edit the page to check if the same issue will occur.